# c code segmentation fault "SIGSEGV" using gdb debugger

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, while-loop, segmentation-fault

I have a code that scans an entire directory for .wor files, and extract info from them.  When I run the file on a directory with 5 .wor files, it works perfectly.  But when i try to run it on a directory with 70+ .wor files, it gives me an "Memery fault(coredump" error.

So i tried to debug the code with gdb, and here is what i got:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x7af9fcbc in _sbrk () from /usr/lib/libc.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0x7af9fcbc in _sbrk () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#1  0x7af9db7c in _sigfillset () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#2  0x7af9bfe8 in __thread_callback_np () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#3  0x7afa0e64 in malloc () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#4  0x7b001160 in _findbuf () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#5  0x7afff7f4 in _filbuf () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#6  0x7afff404 in __fgets_unlocked () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#7  0x7afff5fc in fgets () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#8  0x2c14 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7dff11b4) at book2.c:99
```

I looked at line 99 and i have the command: while( fgets(buff, 100,fs) != NULL ), I do not know c well enough to find where the error is, any help here would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char directory[100];
char buff[100];
char delims[] = " :=";
char *result = NULL;
char *customer;
char *device;
char *testprog;
char *software;
char *dutboardid;
char *corlbox;
char *testerid;
char *temp;
char *buffer;
int i=0;
DIR * FD;
struct dirent* in_file;
int c=0;


printf ("Enter directory:");                                   
    scanf ("%s",directory);


    FILE * ft = fopen ( "workorderlist.csv", "w" ) ;    /* Open file to write to*/
    if ( ft == NULL )
    {
           puts ( "Cannot open target file" ) ;
           exit( 1 ) ;
    }


fprintf (ft, "Work Order,Customer,Device,Test Program,Software,DUT_board_id,Corl box, Tempurature, Test Station\n");



/* Open Directory*/

if (NULL == (FD = opendir (directory))) 
    {

        puts ("Cannot open directory");

    return 1;
    }


    while ((in_file = readdir(FD))) 
    {

    if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
        continue;
    if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))    
        continue;



    /* Open files to read from  */

buffer = (char*) malloc (200);
sprintf(buffer, "%s/%s", directory, in_file->d_name);


size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (len >= 4 && memcmp(buffer + len - 4, ".wor", 4) == 0)   /* checks if file ends with .wor */
{

FILE * fs = fopen(buffer, "r");       /* open file to read */

customer = "0";
device = "0";
testprog = "0";
software = "0";
dutboardid = "0";
corlbox = "0";
testerid = "0";
temp = "0";

    if (fs == NULL)
    {
        puts ("Cannot open source file");

        return 1;
    }

    /* Scanning each file for targeted words: */


while( fgets(buff, 100,fs) != NULL )      
{   



 result = strtok( buff, delims );          
    while(result != NULL){   


            if((strcmp(result,"Customer")==0)){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        customer = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(customer, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(customer)+1;i++){ if(customer[i] == '\n') break; }
        customer[i] = ' ';
        }

            if((strcmp(result,"name")==0)){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        customer = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(customer, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(customer)+1;i++){ if(customer[i] == '\n') break; }
        customer[i] = ' ';
        }


            if(strcmp(result,"device")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        device = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(device, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(device)+1;i++){ if(device[i] == '\n') break; } 
        device[i] = ' ';
        }


            if(strcmp(result,"test_prog")==0 || strcmp(result, "testprog")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        testprog = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(testprog, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(testprog)+1;i++){ if(testprog[i] == '\n') break; } 
        testprog[i] = ' ';
        }


            if(strcmp(result,"Rev")==0 || strcmp(result,"use")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        software = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(software, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(software)+1;i++){ if(software[i] == '\n') break; } 
        software[i] = ' ';
        }

        if(strcmp(result,"rev")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        software = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(software, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(software)+1;i++){ if(software[i] == '\n') break; } 
        software[i] = ' ';
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"DUT_board_id")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        dutboardid = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dutboardid, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(dutboardid)+1;i++){ if(dutboardid[i] == '\n') break; } 
        dutboardid[i] = ' ';
        }                   

            if(strcmp(result,"box")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        corlbox = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(corlbox, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(corlbox)+1;i++){ if(corlbox[i] == '\n') break; } 
        corlbox[i] = ' ';
        }

        if(strcmp(result,"Tester_id")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        testerid = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(testerid, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(testerid)+1;i++){ if(testerid[i] == '\n') break; } 
        testerid[i] = ' ';
        }

        if(strcmp(result,"@")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        temp = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(temp, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(temp)+1;i++){ if(temp[i] == '\n') break; } 
        temp[i] = ' ';
        }


        result = strtok(NULL,delims);
    }

}

if (strcmp(customer, "0")==0){
customer = "N/A";
}
if (strcmp(device, "0")==0){
device = "N/A";
}
if (strcmp(testprog, "0")==0){
testprog = "N/A";
}
if (strcmp(software,"0")==0){
software = "N/A";
}
if (strcmp(dutboardid, "0")==0){
dutboardid = "N/A";
}
if (strcmp(corlbox, "0")==0){
corlbox = "N/A";
}
if (strcmp(testerid, "0")==0){
testerid = "N/A";
}
if (strcmp(temp, "0")==0){
temp = "N/A";
}

fprintf (ft, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", in_file->d_name, customer, device, testprog, software, dutboardid, corlbox, temp, testerid);


printf(in_file->d_name);
printf("\n");
fclose (fs) ;
c++;

}
}
printf("Total Workorders Found: %d (Info saved to workorderlist.csv)\n", c);
    fclose ( ft ) ;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The heap is probably corrupted before this SIGSEGV happens. If you're on Linux, try running your program under *valgrind*: it's a great tool to find this kind of errors.

Comment: "Cannot open directory" sounds like an error message.  As such, it belongs on stderr.  `man perror`

Comment: I do not see any free although you use malloc within the loop!

Comment: I am on UNIX.  Does valgrind still work?

Comment: Formatting your code better will help you understand it.

Comment: You are also not checking the result of strtok, which may be null

Comment: i did check:  result = strtok( buff, delims );          
     while(result != NULL){

Comment: @ Mario The Spoon, where is the correct place to insert the free()? inside of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take this example:

```
customer = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(customer, result);
for(i=0;i<strlen(customer)+1;i++){ if(customer[i] == '\n') break; }
customer[i] = ' ';
```

It copies result, which takes up `strlen(result)+1` bytes. You then copy in result into customer. After that, you search for a '\n' in the string. What happens if there isn't a '\n' in the string? What value is `i`?

I'm pretty sure the problem is that at some point or another, this style of code, is writing outside the allocated memory - since I don't know exactly what your input is, I can't say which of the several copies of this code is going wrong, but I'd bet that is what happens. That in turn means some data in the heap-structure itself is being corrupted, so at some point when malloc is called, it uses this bad data in the code.

Comment: any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, make sure you don't write outside the valid range of your allocated memory. For example, if `i >= strlen(x)`, then you should not be writing to `[i]` in the above code, since that will overwrite the marker for the end of the string.

Comment: I am trying to allocate the memory by using free(), but not having any luck

Comment: Eh? That sounds a bit like "I'm trying to make water run up this stream". free() is used to DEALLOCATE memory. How about you post your current code. Have you fixed the code that is writing outside of the array, like I described above?

Comment: Sorry i dont think i see where this code is writing outside of the range?  This part of the code supposedly takes the customer name, and remove the space or "\n" at the end of the word so i can later put it into the .csv file.  After i break the line into tokens shouldn't there always be a "\n" after each token?

Comment: And if there is no \n for some reason?

Comment: but you are right, i think the problem is here somewhere, since gdb shows the error is at the while loop this part of the code is in "while( fgets(buff, 100,fs) != NULL )".

Comment: would it make sense if i change it to { if (customer[i] == '\n' || customer[i] == ' ') break;}?

Comment: all this part of the code is supposed to do is remove the unwanted space after the word i want (which is stored in the customer string).  Is there a more cleaner way to do this so i can avoid writing outside of the allocated memory?

Comment: I would simply put the "replace newline with space" inside the if-statement that checks for the newline. That way, if there is no newline within the string, you don't try to write something somewhere it doesn't belong.

Comment: I would personally not use `malloc` for this either. Since you know the max length of the string [at least, you have a fixed size string to read into], you could just use that size string to store the final result too. Given that a malloc'd piece of memory is at least 16 bytes larger than the string you allocate, plus the size is usually rounded to the nearest 16 bytes as well, you probably waste almost the same amount as you "save" on using malloc.

Comment: sometimes the string is as long as "/home/product1/Customers/Cortina/IXF18103EE_B0_FT_2.0_90C", so if i was to create a string to store that into, how much memory would that be?

Comment: I may have counted wrong, but abou 60 characters to store that filename. If you use char str[60];, you'll use 60 bytes of stack. If you use `char *str = malloc(60);` it would be rounded up to 64 bytes, and then take an addition 16 or 32 bytes, so 80 or 96 bytes. Plus you have to malloc/free the memory later, so you are using more code as well.

Answer (score 1):

out of memory.

for example, you call malloc and assigned it to "customer" inside a loop, and never seems deallocate the memory.

you have a memory leak, eventually your memory usage hit the system limit.

Comment: are you refering to the "buffer = (char*) malloc (200);" part?  So should i add a code to clear the sbuffer string everytime it loops back?

Comment: and also all customers, temp ... YES ADD THE CODE

Comment: but i did assign customers, temp, device etc strings to 0 at the beginning of the while loop, doesn't that deallocate the memory?